# How to clone newly set firefox profile to all Linux users?

Tags: linux, command-line, firefox, terminal, linux-mint

I installed Linux Mint on a PC for a friend and her family. I made two changes to the Firefox settings after installing: I added an ad-blocker and I set up Google as default search engine.

I would like to clone this profile to all users. I tried all of:

- Copy entire Firefox settings (`~/.mozilla`) folder. When I do that Firefox does not start on other profiles, saying: "Firefox is already running but nor responding.", even though there is not a single Firefox process.
- Copy only the profile. Firefox couldn't locate it.

How can I do this, ideally using CLI? I need to save time, and setting everything manually is very tedious.

Comment: Try to copy-paste the whole `~/.mozilla` folder to a new PC.

Comment: That's what I meant by *"Copy entire Firefox settings folder"*. When I did that, the firefox wouldn't start, as described in the question.

Comment: Close Firefox before you copy the folder.